# Both or only the first, but never just the second

Tags: word-choice

OK, so the title sounds more like a cryptic crossword clue rather than something that explains my question, so please feel free to make it into something more sensible if you can (and remove this sentence)...

Let's say we have two items, the items do not matter but for this example let's say the first is "fish" and the second is "chips".

If I were serving these items I might ask one of the following questions:

> "Would you like fish **or** chips?" - implying that they could only choose one or the other.
>
> "Would you like fish **and** chips?" - implying that they could only have both items together.

**Now the question**: Is there a word (or two) that could replace and/or in the above sentences that would imply that they can choose to have fish only, both fish and chips, or neither of them, but **not** chips only?

---

To try and clarify my requirements, here is the original example that inspired me to seek out an answer...

Originally I read the following sentence on StackOverflow (a different SE site for those that don't know):

> You should probably use javascript or jQuery to accomplish this

The problem I find with this sentence is that "jQuery" is a javascript library and cannot exist without "javascript", therefore the "or" is technically inaccurate. However, to replace the "or" with "and" would also be inaccurate because you could choose only "javascript" as "jQuery" is optional (it would just make it easier). And, of course, neither can be chosen.

Comment: *“Would you like fries with your fish?”*

Comment: @tchrist: But that is assuming that they want fish. In this example they should be allowed to choose neither - which perhaps I should have specified... will edit

Comment: Can I serve you some fish with or without fries?

Comment: This is unrelated and pedantic, but when you say "If I *was* serving ..." it would be better to say "If I *were* serving...". This is because your 'if' puts the sentence into the subjunctive mood.

Comment: As I am not a common user over here, could somebody explain the downvotes? I fail to see how this question doesn't fit in with the "[help](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" guidelines. Specifically, `Questions on the following topics are welcomed here: Word choice and usage`.

Comment: Not my downvote, but perhaps it's because this cannot be a real-world situation. A person behind the counter at a fish-and-chip shop would be likely to break the problem down into two questions: "Would you like fish? Would you like chips with that?"

Comment: Honestly, splitting the request up seems more effective. "Would you like to order the fish today? (Customer says yes) Okay, you can get chips on the side with that. Would you like to order those today?". It's longer than one sentence, but sounds less awkward (to me, anyway).

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Perhaps fish and chips wasn't the best example. The requirement is more that the second item relies on the existence of the first item, therefore you cant have only the second item. But you can have the first on its own, or you don't have to have either. I think perhaps people are concentrating on why I would want to say such a sentence, rather than on my actual question

Comment: Isn’t this actually a programming question in disguise?

Comment: @tchrist: not quite, but my curiosity does come from reading something somebody wrote over on Stack Overflow. I will edit in the real example, as that might make more sense (but only for those that have trouble seeing the question through the trees - whatever that means)

Comment: @musefan: Context is very, very important. Make the question generic to get the best answer. How about: "You can choose to have Y if you have X," or, using your example: "You can get chips if you order the fish".

Comment: Concentrating on the *why* is exactly right. "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." Splitting the questions into two is the answer to the practical problem of how to ask in the real-world situation which (presumably) you are facing. If this is **not** the problem you have, you should have asked about that instead.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: But I didn't ask the question "How can I ask a customer if they want fish, and optional have chips with it?". I asked, "Is there a word (or two) that could replace and/or..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the real example,

> You should probably use javascript or jQuery to accomplish this

you can achieve the objective by reversing the order and adding a couple of words to emphasise the difference:

> You should probably use jQuery or just plain JavaScript to accomplish this.

Thus jQuery implies JavaScript; you could have JavaScript without jQuery; or neither.

Comment: I have accepted this answer on the basis that there is no "alternative word" that could be used instead of and/or, and as per my original question, I was looking for the best way to alter the sentence as a backup. If somebody invents (or discovers) a word then let me know ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Converting comment to answer

> Can/May I serve you some fish with or without chips?

**UPDATE**: Would of course have been lovely to have seen the original reason for the question since I have [A LOT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) more experience with JavaScript/jQuery than fish&chips

Since JavaScript is built-in whatever device that could run jQuery, the sentence Andrew wrote, is understandable by anyone versed in the art.
jQuery is a JavaScript library so the *or* relates only to plain JavaScript or `vanilla.js` as some people like to call it now

Comment: I feel that this would prompt a second repeat of the "with or without chips?" part if the person said "yes"... but perhaps it is the simplest way to achieve my requirements.

Comment: I would answer: Yes please, with chips

Answer (score 2):

This is not a word to use, but a convention, and not as clear when spoken, but I would write:

> You should probably use javascript (possibly along with jQuery) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Converting comment to answer:

You could phrase it this way:

"You can choose Y if you have X."
"If you have X, you can choose to get Y".

Answer (score 0):

You could describe this process as an *[incremental](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/increment) choice*. You are making a base choice (whether or not to use javascript) and then a choice about whether to add a supplement (whether or not to add jQuery to the use of javascript).

The implication is that you cannot make the second choice unless you affirmatively make the first choice.